# WCF Stripping detail from System.SecurityException

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I am implementing IErrorHandler for a WCF service, with the intention of automatically logging the messages.

During testing I decided to throw a `System.SecurityException` with an inner exception and some user defined data:

```
try
{
    LevelTwo();
}
catch (Exception innerEx)
{
    var outerEx = new SecurityException("Is security special?", innerEx);
    outerEx.Data.Add("foo", "bar");
    throw outerEx;
}
```

Yet when it hits my `ProvideFault` method in my error handler it has already been converted to a `System.ServiceModel.FaultException` with a Message of "Access is denied". The original message, exception type, data and inner exception have all been lost, and I cannot log them. Other exception types work as expected, exposing all those properties for logging.

I presume that there is a framework implementation of `IErrorHandler` that is hit first, and converts it, stripping the detail and providing a generic message, which is all well and good generally, but not when I want to log the details.

Somebody [has posted](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a6f786f8-93a7-4f62-a233-e53a2df7110e/wcf-converts-securityexception?forum=wcf) the same issue on MSDN but didn't get any particularly good answers.

***Ideally I would like to change the order of the error handlers so that mine is hit first - is this possible?***

If not - is it possible to remove the existing handler, and if so, are there any undesirable consequences?

***EDIT***
Following Christian's advice below it appears that the exception is getting caught by the code in `SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke()`

```
catch (System.Security.SecurityException e)
{
    DiagnosticUtility.TraceHandledException(e, TraceEventType.Warning);
    throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError
        (AuthorizationBehavior.CreateAccessDeniedFaultException());
}
```

I think this means that Security Exceptions are a very special case, and that there probably isn't a good way around this, but I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a proper computer right now, so I cannot test it myself, but I think WCF indeed converts *any* SecurityException into what you observe.

If you look at the complete call stack of your "rethrown" SecurityExceptions, you should see stack frames hinting at the location where they originate. With that information you can look into http://sourceof.net/ to look at the relevant code.

Having that said, there are multiple implementations of `IOperationInvoker` in WCF that handle the different calling styles (async, sync, etc.) of service operations.

For an example see:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/SyncMethodInvoker.cs,181

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/AsyncMethodInvoker.cs,140

So, I think the order of IErrorHandlers is nothing that helps with this issue, as the exception gets converted/stripped/replaced before error handlers are even called.

I would consider creating my own fault type for security issues, like a SecurityFault type and then throwing that as `FaultException<SecurityFault>(...)`. That fault type could have all the properties you want. Additionally, since the fault type is a DataContract and the properties are DataMembers, you don't risk getting serialization issues, because you may inadvertently put non-serializable data into the exception's `Data`.

Comment: Thanks Christian - that's some useful information. I'm trying to do this for logging on the server side, so I'm not really bothered about serialization or the exception the client sees and of course I can *choose* not to throw security exceptions in my own code, but I would prefer to be able to catch and log ***all*** exceptions

Comment: But serialization is still an issue: when you have logged the exception it will get passed on and _is_ serialized - unless you also replace it in the `IErrorHandler.ProvideFault` method with something safe (been there, done that). Frankly, I haven't seen that SecurityException-behavior before (but also never explicitly looked at it). Mind you that there are some exceptions you cannot log anyway (like said serialization errors), because they can occur _after_ your error handler has ran. Only chance here is to use WCF tracing in case you have such "late" (or "early" for incoming requests) errors